# PayPal button and jQuery are not working together

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, paypal

I am not trying to connect/integrate PayPal and jQuery in any way... Simply used bootstrap default template and pasted PayPal button code without any changes. Basically I cannot click PayPal button if this code is present:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I have tried moving code above and code of PayPal button around... not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

got it working!
I have changed

```
type="submit"
```

to

```
type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();"
```